# ¿Cómo guardo e imprimo los elementos de un arreglo string?

Tags: c++, array, string

En un ejercicio me pidieron construir un programa que permita recolectar los destinos más frecuentes para una empresa de Taxi y las estaciones más frecuentes para una empresa de Bus.

Un ejemplo de input sería:

```
Rappido
3
Aeropuerto Jorge Chavez
Costa Verde
Cerro San Cristobal
Rutta
2
Arequipa
Trujillo
```

Y el output debe quedar así más o menos:

```
Rappido tiene los siguientes lugares mas visitados:
1) Aeropuerto Jorge Chavez
2) Costa Verde
3) Cerro San Cristobal

Rutta tiene los siguientes lugares mas visitados:
1) Arequipa
2) Trujillo
```

Tengo el siguiente código, sin embargo, al compilarlo me arroja el siguiente error: Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault. Entonces, ¿cómo puedo iterar y guardar los nombres de los lugares en cada arreglo string y luego imprimirlos? o ¿qué está mal en mi código y cómo lo puedo solucionar?. Desde ya, muchas gracias :D

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string nombreTaxi, nombreBus;
    int cantidadTaxi=0, cantidadBus=0;
    string destinos[cantidadTaxi];
    string estaciones[cantidadBus];

    getline(cin,nombreTaxi);
    cin >> cantidadTaxi;
    int i=0;
    while(i<cantidadTaxi)
    {
      getline(cin,destinos[i]);
      i++;
    }
    getline(cin,nombreBus);
    cin >> cantidadBus;
    int j=0;
    while(j<cantidadBus)
    {
      getline(cin,estaciones[j]);
      j++;
    }
    cout << nombreTaxi << " tiene los siguientes lugares mas visitados: " << endl;
    for (int k=0; k<cantidadTaxi;k++)
    {
        cout << k+1 << ") " << destinos[k] << "\n";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << nombreBus << " tiene los siguientes lugares mas visitados: " << endl;
    for (int l=0; l<cantidadBus;l++)
    {
        cout << l+1 << ") " << estaciones[l] << "\n";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tanto `destinos` como `estaciones` son arreglos nulos porque los creas con 0 elementos, por lo tanto, cuando intentas poner un elemento a estos `destinos[i]` te da error porque esa variable no tiene reservado espacio para ningún elemento. Utiliza un `vector` para estas variables.

Comment: Si tu compilador soporta VLA, deberías pedir la cantidad de elementos para cada arreglo primero. Sino sucede lo que Juan te dijo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las formaciones<sup>1</sup> en C++ deben tener un tamaño conocido en tiempo de compilación, una variable es un valor conocido en tiempo de ejecución y como tal no puede usarse como tamaño de formación:

```
int cantidadTaxi=0, cantidadBus=0; // Esto son variables
string destinos[cantidadTaxi];     // Esto es incorrecto
string estaciones[cantidadBus];    // Esto es incorrecto
```

Por otro lado, el tamaño de `destinos` y `estaciones` no cambiará *automágicamente* cuando leas las variables, el código C++ se ejecuta de arriba a abajo y lo que pasa en líneas posteriores no afecta a lo que pasó en líneas anteriores.

```
cin >> cantidadTaxi; // No afecta al tamaño de destinos

// ...

cin >> cantidadBus; // No afecta al tamaño de estaciones
```

Si quieres colecciones de datos cuyo tamaño cambie dinámicamente, usa contenedores. En tu caso probablemente `std::map` y `std::vector` sea lo adecuado:

```
using estaciones_t = std::vector<std::string>;
using destinos_t = std::map<std::string, estaciones_t>;

std::stringstream ss{datos};
std::string destino;
destinos_t destinos;

while (std::getline(ss, destino))
{
    // Se ha leido un destino, leemos cuantas estaciones tiene
    unsigned estaciones;
    ss >> estaciones;
    ss.ignore(1);
    // Creamos la entrada en destinos
    auto [iterador, b] = destinos.insert({destino, estaciones_t(estaciones)});

    // Leemos las estaciones
    for (int indice = 0; ss && (indice != estaciones); ++indice)
        std::getline(ss, iterador->second[indice]);
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVNbb9owFH7Gv@KMSTQRl67dGwGkirdpe6HTXiiq3Pg0eA125gubWvHXy06cmhpNk5LYPtfv@05cNs24rLmqjsePUpW1Fwgzqa0zyHcL9m4ji1RVatnxJj3usXTanKXEKqzUyjr80xjg3mkQ3GkLc1j1sxVvGik0@8xu0OjGoyH/F20qhOWW7/GZLQkMhx9oBLIlGqPhlitYGmmdfuA1W3nnOLtmNwZ/edlw9t34n7Kudd4vGJPKwY5LleXshfW8JQ6AVLCUWqG9d4TCOjGdduhnYf9GtYjxghKk0kk0UU9DR2clKZH1Em@nAlj7EngfijNvrE7WpE/ctqV@b2WNkIWcCl0tFWbWjmJMnrMeUetdXsItwpZDjSQoeBUDRmTBHQleeq4ctwlYcBIVUrJXVlYKReIjQD1rYbH4xzahUG0wu8qLru@yJUgNag6onOGiXU8cKCZMfS0dkk@bETxsSMnon0hlaezZywlvqmb2fsgPeatH2/Frx6g@Y0OuR20ga2culZAlUpdPBSkPg0FrDqYP8yQlL2A47BwkY9DxbDgxsjg50glEQuOFRfrFxbqrtAm6HBg9rAX7rb1OnUD0hp@AdUjDvejuxGD9NIL9BqYnXd7mGrqW2juYzeCp/fS7sYVqNDZPB0ezrH3FDa07EmUvrXQEzU7vVL@IwnTM5DPepwKR3krQZj9pXRlJkiilxP8UipCirkO4ygO6nADSuo9qtIeLO3WRiGLQeaNoNuxwPL6WjzWv7HFMZeflcHjN/wI)</kbd>.

---

###### <sup>1</sup>También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *array*.

Comment: Genial!!, conseguí corregir mi código gracias a tu explicación :D